# How do I split a data frame into groups of a fixed size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I am working with large data frames (>100 000 rows and multiple columns). I need to sort the data frame and then split it into equal sized groups of a predefined size. If there are rows left over (i.e. if the number of rows is not divisible by the size of the group), then any smaller groups need to be removed from the data frame.

e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` with a group size of `3`
should be split into `[1, 2, 3]`, `[4, 5, 6]`, `[7, 8, 9]` and `10` should be discarded.

I have a solution where I can create a new column using

```
list(range(len(df.index) // group_size)) * group_size
```

and then use `sort()`, followed by `group_by()` to group the rows together. Afterwards I can `filter` to remove any groups which are smaller than `group_size`.

Example working code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
group_size = 3  

numbers = list(range(len(df.index) // group_size)) * group_size
numbers.sort()
numbers = pd.Series(numbers)
df = pd.concat([df, numbers], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df.columns = ['value', 'group number']

groups = df.groupby('group number').filter(lambda x: len(x) == group_size)
print(groups)
```

This works perfectly. Unfortunately I have large data frames and it takes far too long to run. Is there an alternative to my approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you a list of DataFrames:

```
lst = [df.iloc[i:i+group_size] for i in range(0,len(df)-group_size+1,group_size)]
```

It just uses built-in indexing, so it should be pretty fast. The fidgeting with the stop index takes care of discarding the last frame if it's too small - you can also break it down with

```
lst = [df.iloc[i:i+group_size] for i in range(0,len(df),group_size)]
if len(lst[-1]) < group_size:
   lst.pop()
```

Comment: This is so beautifully simple. Thanks for this! I would love to vote but don't yet have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Delimit with a slice, and then ffill().

```
df['group'] = df[::3]
df['group'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Now you can do a grouping and discard the groups that are too small.

```
# df has a RangeIndex, so we get to slice 
group_size = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
slices = df[::group_size]

# but you don't want the group number to be the ordinal at the slices
# so make a copy of the slice to assign good group numbers to it (or get a chained assignment warning)
slices=slices.copy()
slices['group'] = [i for i in range(len(slices))]
df['group'] = slices['group']

# ffill with the nice group numbers
df['group'].ffill(inplace=True)

#now trim the last group
last_group = df['group'].max()
if len(df[df['group']==last_group]) < group_size:
    df = df[df['group'] != last_group]

print(df)
```

Times:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
print(pd.__version__)


def test1():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
    #print(df)
    group_size = 3
    numbers = list(range(len(df.index) // group_size)) * group_size
    numbers.sort()
    numbers = pd.Series(numbers)
    df = pd.concat([df, numbers], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
    df.columns = ['value', 'group number']
    groups = df.groupby('group number').filter(lambda x: len(x) == group_size)
    #print(groups)

def test2():
    # Won't work well because there is no easy way to calculate the remainder that should
    # not be grouped.  But cut() is good for discretizing continuous values
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
    num_groups = len(df.index)/3
    df['group'] = pd.cut(df['a'], num_groups, right=False)
    #print(df)

def test3():
    # df has a RangeIndex, so we get to slice 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
    df['group'] = df[::3]
    df['group'].ffill(inplace=True)
    #print(df['group'])

def test4():
    # A mask can also be used
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
    df['group'] = df[df.index % 3 == 0]
    df['group'].ffill(inplace=True)
    #print(df)

def test5():
    # maybe go after grouping with iloc
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # data frame has been sorted before this point and the rows are in the correct order
    group = 0
    for i in range(0,len(df), 3):
        df.loc[i:i+3, 'group'] = group
        group+=1
    #print(df)


funcs = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]
for func in funcs:
    print(func.__name__)
    a = dt.now()
    for i in range(1000):
        func()
    b = dt.now()
    print(b-a)
```

Comment: Lots more approaches, and they're nearly all faster than mine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of Perigon's answer.  In my case, I didn't want to throw away the last few, so this shows how to put the remainder in a final list.  I was reading a CSV, and wanted to do multiprocessing, so I will pass the smaller dataframes to separate processes, and can't lose any rows from the CSV. So in my case desired_number_per_group is set to the same number of processes I want to multi-process.

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    test_dict = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict)
    
    print ('Size of dataFrame=', len(df.index))
    desired_number_of_groups = 4
    group_size = int(len(df.index) / (desired_number_of_groups))
    print("group_size=", group_size)
    remainder_size = len(df.index) % group_size
    print("remainder_size=", remainder_size)
    df_split_list = [df.iloc[i:i + group_size] for i in range(0, len(df) - group_size + 1, group_size)]
    print("Number of split_dataframes=", len(df_split_list))
    if remainder_size > 0:
        df_remainder = df.iloc[-remainder_size:len(df.index)]
        df_split_list.append(df_remainder)
    print("Revised Number of split_dataframes=", len(df_split_list))
    print("Splitting complete, verifying counts")
    
    count_all_rows_after_split = 0
    for index, split_df in enumerate(df_split_list):
        print("split_df:", index, " size=", len(split_df.index))
        count_all_rows_after_split += len(split_df.index)
    
    if count_all_rows_after_split != len(df.index):
        raise Exception('count_all_rows_after_split = ', count_all_rows_after_split,
                         " but original CSV DataFrame has count =", len(df.index)
                         )
```

Rich did a better job with his unit test cases.  I just tested test_dict with 1:17, then 1:18, then 1:19, then 1:20, then 1:21)